# Confusion related to intractability in topic models

Tags: optimization, inference, posterior, topic-models

[image]

I was reading this paper related to [topic models](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.110.4050&rep=rep1&type=pdf). I am a bit confused why the marginal likelihood is not tractable and how converting the graphical model into the new one actually helps. First I don't understand how the coupling between $\beta$ and $\theta$ result in making it intractable. It points to a reference. But I cannot access the article (Dickey 1983). So I cannot understand why it is intractable. can anyone please provide me some information?

Answer (score 2):

The intractability comes from too many possible configurations of topic assignments $z$ in a document. Suppose we have $N_d$ words in document $d$, then the possible configuration is $K^{N_d}$ for a single document, let alone the whole corpus.

There are two ways to solve this, variational inference and Collapsed Gibbs sampling.

For variational inference, after drawing the plate diagram on the right, the z only depends on $\phi$.

For Collapsed Gibbs Sampling, we randomly assign a topic to z and update it later.